# Android app in Amazon Market not showing on Kindle Fire

Tags: android, kindle-fire

What is the trick to getting an app to show in the Amazon Market on the Kindle Fire?

I have submitted my android app to Amazon Marketplace and it was approved months ago.  When I search for that app (through Amazon Marketplace) on my Motorola Xoom, or my wife's Nexus One, I am able to find it.  Search on the Kindle, its nowhere to be found.

I read Amazon's suggestions at https://developer.amazon.com/help/faq.html regarding the Kindle Fire and it doesn't give any hints why it wouldn't show up.  I have the following relevant entries in my Manifest:

```
<supports-screens
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:anyDensity="true"
    />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
```

Comment: More detail.  When I force a redirect from inside the app (after being side-loaded) to the marketplace, I get _Not Compatible  XXX is incompatible with your device.  You cannot purchase this app from this device._

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Amazon approve apps separately for the Kindle Fire. What is the nature of your application? Amazon are blocking certain apps from the Kindle Fire, seemingly where it competes with their services, like eReader apps.

Comment: I also think same. I have uploaded 5 apps all are approved but none of them is visible on kindle. All apps are related to eBooks.

Comment: After struggling all this time, experimenting with minSdkVersion a bunch, I believe that Amazon didn't like that I was selling music from within the app.  What is interesting is that I tried using Amazon's music services but they explicitly identified in the terms and conditions that we could NOT play their clips on a mobile device.  So I have no choice it seems.  It shows for other mobile devices which is bizarre but THAT market is basically nonexistent.   All that work I put into Amazon in-app billing... dang.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried increasing the minSdkVersion?

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />
```

They explicitly say in the Amazon's suggestions:

```
Target: Android 2.3.4 - API Level 10
```

I'm using that sdk version in my app and I can find it the KF store without problems.

Comment: i did try this.. with no success