# App not showing on kindle devices (only showing on non-amazon devices)

Tags: android, kindle-fire

I created a simple app and uploaded to Amazon store. **The problem is it is only downloadable on non-Amazon Android devices**. The app is simple with only one activity. The activity contains only one web view which loads up the following URL - www.myromancereads.com . If I directly install/debug/run the app on a real kindle device, it works fine. Below is my manifest file:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.brian.romancereads"
        android:versionCode="2"
        android:versionName="2.0" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/CustomTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.brian.romancereads.Main" 
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Here are two screenshots from amazon appstore:-

1> http://www.greenbean.in/images/rr1.jpg

2> http://www.greenbean.in/images/rr2.jpg

I have followed all guidelines for Kindle fire development, but still the app is not available for Kindle devices. I fail to understand what is the problem. Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks...

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/a/10382534/1589566 Amazon blocks apps related to eBooks for Kindle.

Comment: Yes, I read this post. But that is just an assumption. Did Amazon themselves mention anywhere that apps related to eBooks will not be compatible with Kindle Fire?

Answer (score 0):

This may be your device targetting settings in the portal itself and not a code issue.  Screenshot rr2 is showing its not available for those devices on the Appstore.  Screenshot rr1 is part of the Appstore Developer Select Program which requires targeting Kindle devices.  I did a post on our developer blog that has more program [details here](https://developer.amazon.com/post/Tx8078PSPPWVPF/Introducing-the-Amazon-Appstore-Developer-Select-Program.html).

Can you go to your [dashboard here](https://developer.amazon.com/myapps.html) under Apps and Services, select My Apps and then click on the App name in question.  You should see a "Binary Files" tab and a section for "Device Support".  Can you verify that you have checked off Kindle Devices there?

Here is a screenshot[image: of device Support for one of my own apps]

My hunch is that you may only have "All non-Amazon Android devices based on my manifest" checked currently.

Comment: Thanks for replying! I have added all devices...see this screenshot - http://www.greenbean.in/images/rr3.jpg . What else could be the reason?